# Multistatement Queries in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking to send multiple read queries to a Postgres database in order to reduce the number of trips that need to be made to a painfully remote database. Is there anything in `libpq` that supports this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [asynchronous handling functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-async.html) in libpq. On the linked page it says:

> Using PQsendQuery and PQgetResult solves one of PQexec's problems: If
>   a command string contains multiple SQL commands, the results of those
>   commands can be obtained individually. (This allows a simple form of
>   overlapped processing, by the way: the client can be handling the
>   results of one command while the server is still working on later
>   queries in the same command string.)

For example, you should be able to call `PQsendQuery` with a string containing multiple queries, then repeatedly call `PQgetResult` to get the result sets. `PQgetResult` returns NULL when there are no more result sets to obtain.

If desired, you can also avoid your application blocking while it waits for these queries to execute (described in more detail on the linked page).

Comment: `PQgetResult`'s docs say that it "waits for the next result". What does that exactly mean? This seem to imply that the number of trips to the database won't actually be reduced.

Comment: If by 'round trips' you mean send a set of commands, then get back a set of results, then yes there will only be one round trip. Note that libpq keeps a connection alive as long as you are connected to the database - this is different to eg. http, where for each request, a TCP connection is made to the host, the request sent, a response received, then the connection closed. libpq sends the request(s), the server executes the commands, sends back one or more result sets through the connection which remains open the whole time.