# cursors: atomic MOVE then FETCH?

Tags: postgresql

### the intent

Basically, pagination: have a `CURSOR` (created using [`DECLARE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-declare.html) outside any function here, but that can be changed if need be) concurrently addressed to retrieve batches of rows, implying moving the cursor position in order to fetch more than one line (`FETCH count` seems to be the only way to fetch more than one line).

### the context

During a more global transaction (i.e. using *one* connection), I want to retrieve a range of rows through a cursor. To do so, I:

- [`MOVE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-move.html) the cursor to the desired position (e.g. `MOVE 42 FROM "mycursor"`)
- *then* [`FETCH`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-fetch.html) the amount of rows (e.g. `FETCH FORWARD 10 FROM "mycursor"`)

However, this transaction is used by many workers (horizontally scaled), each receiving a set of "coordinates" for the cursor, like `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`: the index to `MOVE` to, and the amount of rows to `FETCH`. These workers use the DB connection through HTTP calls to a single DB API which handles the pool of connections and the transactions' liveliness.

Because of this concurrent access to the transaction/connection, I need to ensure atomic execution of the couple "`MOVE` then `FETCH`".

### the setup

- NodeJS workers consuming ranges of rows through a DB API
- NodeJS DB API based on [`pg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) (latest)
- PostgreSQL v10 (can be upgraded if required, all documentation links here are from v12 - latest)

### the tries

- `WITH (MOVE 42 FROM "mycursor") FETCH 10 FROM "mycursor"` produces a syntax error, apparently [`WITH`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) doesn't handle `MOVE`
- `MOVE 42 FROM "mycursor" ; FETCH 10 FROM "mycursor"` as I'm inside a transaction I *suppose* this could work, but anyway I'm using [Node's `pg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) which apparently doesn't handle several statements in the same call to `query()` (no error, but no result yielded, I didn't dig into this too much as it looks like a hack)
- I'm not confident a function would guarantee atomicity, it doesn't seem to be what `PARALLEL UNSAFE` does, and as I'm going to have high concurrency, I'd really love some explicitly written assurances about atomicity...

### the reason

I'd prefer not to rely on `LIMIT`/`OFFSET` as it would require an `ORDER BY` clause to ensure pagination consistency (as per the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-limit.html), `ctrl-f` for "unpredictable"), unless (scrollable, without hold) cursors prove to be way more resource-consuming. "Way more" because it has to be weighed with the `INSENSITIVE` behavior of cursors that would allow me not to acquire a lock on the underlying table during the whole process. If it's proven that pagination in this context is not feasible using cursors, I'll fall back to this solution, unless you have something better to suggest!

### the human side

Hello, and thanks in advance for the help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can share connections, but you cannot to share transactions. This request is impossible for this context. Good tools doesn't share connections, when any transaction is used in this connection.

Comment: Sharing a connection on which a transaction has been opened works well, I don't see the problem?

Comment: You cannot to share connections with opened transactions - in this case, and in few other. The most big problem is transaction isolation - nobody expect so more users can share one transaction. Lot of things stops work.

Comment: Ah this is already sorted out: every DB call goes through the DB API. This DB API is coded in JavaScript, so it's not "sharing the transaction" like "multithreading access", it's sharing like "JS is single-threaded so in the end it's always one call after the other". I'd just like to avoid having to deport the atomicity of the `MOVE` then `FETCH` into the code (as the network overhead would be important). I hope I'm clear... :)

Comment: @StockOverflaw - unfortunately I have nothing about NodeJS DB API. Just I know some about Postgres. `MOVE` and `FETCH` are two separate statements, and there are only two ways, how to join it together to one network call. a) you can use PLpgSQL function with refcursor parameter, b) you can use multistatement call - native postgres api allow to execute more statements separated by `;`. But not all API supports this feature.

Comment: The b) option I'd like to avoid indeed, but the a) option: you mean that if `MOVE` and `FETCH` are performed inside a function, it is *guaranteed* to be executed atomically? If so, is there any documentation I missed?

Comment: @StockOverflaw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049100/multistatement-queries-in-postgres

Comment: Hello, this was the right approach apparently: having `MOVE`/`FETCH` in a SQL function (using `json` type and `row_to_json` function to abstract any table structure) revealed no inconsistencies so far, thank you for pointing me in this direction!